# How to log Unhandled TimeoutError in Winstonjs logger?

Tags: javascript, node.js, logging, error-handling, winston

I've got a node application in which I use [Winstonjs](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston) as a logger. In my logger I've got a specific part for logging exceptions like this:

```
const myFormat = winston.format.printf(info => {
    return `${info.timestamp} ${info.level}: ${info.message}`;
});
const logger = winston.createLogger({
    level: "debug",
    format: winston.format.combine(winston.format.timestamp(), myFormat),  // winston.format.json(),
    transports: [
        new winston.transports.File({filename: "logs/error.log", level: 'error'}),
        new winston.transports.File({filename: 'logs/combined.log'}),
    ],
    exceptionHandlers: [
        new winston.transports.File({ filename: 'logs/exceptions.log' }),
        new winston.transports.File({ filename: 'logs/combined.log' })
    ],
    exitOnError: false
});
```

So any exceptions should be logged in both `logs/combined.log` and `logs/exceptions.log`.

When I run my program I now sometimes get the error below in my STDOUT, which comes from [Sequelizejs](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/) which I use to write to my MySQL db.

```
Unhandled rejection TimeoutError: ResourceRequest timed out
    at ResourceRequest._fireTimeout (/root/mmjs/node_modules/generic-pool/lib/ResourceRequest.js:62:17)
    at Timeout.bound (/root/mmjs/node_modules/generic-pool/lib/ResourceRequest.js:8:15)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:424:11)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:288:5)
    at listOnTimeout (timers.js:251:5)
    at Timer.processTimers (timers.js:211:10)
```

This error only shows up in stdout (when running my program manually), and it doesn't show up in either the `combined.log` or the `exceptions.log`. It could be because this is an error and not an exception. I'm not sure how I can log this correctly though.

(I guess I can [wrap my whole code in a try/catch](https://www.reddit.com/r/ProgrammerHumor/comments/6ayz26/defensive_programming_done_right/), but I guess there's a better way.. :-) )

Could anybody help me out logging this and similar uncaught errors?

Comment: so your nodejs program is killed with that error ? What is running your nodejs program ? pm2 ?

Comment: @Cétia - Currently I'm just running it manually: `node index.js`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **process** is referring to **node**. Try to add a unhandledRejection check in your index.js or use [proper winston exception handling](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston#handling-uncaught-exceptions-with-winston):

```
"use strict";

const winston = require('winston');

const myFormat = winston.format.printf(info => {
    return `${info.timestamp} ${info.level}: ${info.message}`;
});
const logger = winston.createLogger({
    level: "debug",
    format: winston.format.combine(winston.format.timestamp(), myFormat),  // winston.format.json(),
    transports: [
        new winston.transports.File({filename: "logs/error.log", level: 'error'}),
        new winston.transports.File({filename: 'logs/combined.log'}),
    ],
    exceptionHandlers: [
        new winston.transports.File({ filename: 'logs/exceptions.log' }),
        new winston.transports.File({ filename: 'logs/combined.log' })
    ],
    exitOnError: false,
    // handleExceptions: true // Otherwise, you should use this in options.
});

process.on('unhandledRejection', (reason, promise) => {
    logger.debug(reason);
});

process.on('uncaughtException', (err) => {
    logger.debug(err);
});
```

However, look in your package.json file in the same directory as the index.js file. Look in dependencies section for node-pool and change its version to "node-pool": "^3.4.2" since the problem you describe is most likely fixed in the 3.1.8 release.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But on what process should I put this? I'm not running a server but a collection of `setInterval()` calls and a websocket with many actions resulting from received messages. Any idea how to use this?

Comment: The whole thing is only one file: `index.js`. But I don't have any specific process going on. What if I would only have one `setInterval()` with some code in there. Where would I put it then?

Comment: I understand that you can't guess what my code looks like. But what if it was just a bunch of `setInterval()` with some function in it. In that case there is no process to hook it into. What would you do in such a case?

Comment: The process is node, I guess you start your code using **node index.js**?

Comment: Ahhhhh, just now I realise that `process` is a global object and not an instantiation of some class I need to create myself! That should solve it, thanks!

Comment: I am glad to help, I hope it makes you be able to log all the data you want.