# how do I catch error in try catch by using winston in entire application?

Tags: node.js, winston

**winston.js**

```
var options = {
    file: {
        level: 'info',
        filename: `./app.log`,
        handleExceptions: true,
        json: true,
        colorize: false,
        timestamp:true
    },
    console: {
        level: 'debug',
        handleExceptions: true,
        json: false,
        colorize: true,
        timestamp:true
    },
};

// var logger = {}


const logger = new winston.createLogger({
    transports: [
        new winston.transports.File(options.file),
        new winston.transports.Console(options.console)
    ],
    exceptionHandlers: [
        new winston.transports.File(options.file)
      ], 
    exitOnError: false, // do not exit on handled exceptions
});

logger.stream = {
    write: function(message, encoding) {
      // use the 'info' log level so the output will be picked up by both transports (file and console)
      logger.info(message);
      return;
    },
  };

  process.on('uncaughtException', function (err) {
      console.log('err',err)
    logger.error('uncaughtException', { message : err.message, stack : err.stack }); // logging with MetaData
    // process.exit(1); // exit with failure
});

process.on('unhandledRejection', (err, promise) => {
    logger.error('uncaughtException', { message : err.message, stack : err.stack }); // logging })
});

module.exports = logger;
```

**app.js**

```
app.get('/data',async(req,res)=>{
    try {
        let result = await config.data(req);
        console.log(result)
        res.status(200).json({
            code:200,
            message:'Success',
            data:result
        })
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.message)
    }
})
```

This only handles the promise return error and uncaughtException error.

I don't wanna put `logger.error()` in every try catch block.

config.data() is not a function. I wanna catch this error automatically in the entire application.

Someone please help me to solve this problem. I'm stuck at this point in the project.

Answer (score 0):

Usually nodeJS apps define a error handler middleware that catches all the exceptions, logs them and returns a valid response.

```js
app.get('/data', ...);
app.post('/data', ...);
...
// global error handler goes here
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
  logger.error(err)
  res.status(500).send('Something broke!')
})
```

this middleware usually is defined as the last app handler.

Comment: Thanks. But I want to catch the error in try catch block in the entire application.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
app.get('/data', async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        let result = await config.data(req);
        console.log(result)
        res.status(200).json({
            code: 200,
            message: 'Success',
            data: result
        })
    } catch (error) {
        logger.error(`error: ${error.message}`)
        return next(error.message)
    }
})
```

Comment: It's okay. I don't wanna put this `logger.error(error)` in the entire application.

Comment: Then you must create a middleware and pass the handler function as a callback to your handler function, which will allow executing the function within the context of a try/catch where you can apply error handling

Comment: Thanks. But there is a default error handling function like `unhandledRejection` and `uncaughtException`. Here I want to like this to catch the error in a try-catch block in the entire application.

Comment: Refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51916061/how-to-log-unhandled-timeouterror-in-winstonjs-logger

Comment: this one doesn't catch the error from the try-catch block. It only catches the `unhandledRejection`.

Comment: Check this https://medium.com/fortjs/exception-logging-in-nodejs-using-winston-e19d857d356f

Comment: No, this one also only handles the above-mentioned method. It doesn't catch the error in the try-catch block.